# How to change font color of datepicker?

Tags: android, colors, fonts, datepicker

I want to change the font color on the datepicker
because my background is black and the default font on a datepicker also black
I want to change it to white.

**Xml:**

```
        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/dt_tanggal_lahir"
            style="android:datePickerStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />
```